# Auth login is not working for new users in laravel 6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Auth login is not working for the new users in laravel 6 socialite. but the user data is saved in a database. I mean to say When a new user tries to register using laravel socialite(Twitter, Facebook), he/she not auto-login but data saved in the database. I want the user to auto login when he/she register using socialites.

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
use AuthenticatesUsers;
protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;


public function __construct()
{
 //   $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}

public function redirectToProvider($provider)
{
    return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
}


public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{
 try {
    $social_user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
    $authuser = $this->findOrCreateUser($social_user,$provider);

    Auth::login($authuser,true);
    return redirect('/');
  } catch(\Exception $e){

   return redirect('/');
}


}
public function findOrCreateUser($social_user,$provider){

    $authuser = SocialProvider::where('provider_id', $social_user->id)->first();

    if(!$authuser){

          $username = slugify($social_user->getName())."-".mt_rand(10000, 99999);
          $password = rand(1000000000, 99999999999);

          $user = User::firstOrCreate(['email' => $social_user->getEmail()], 
          [
              'username'=> $username,
              'name'=> $social_user->getName(),
              'picture'=> $social_user->getAvatar(),
              'password' => Hash::make($password),
              'ip_address'=> get_user_ip(),
          ]);


      $user->socialProviders()->create(

        ['provider_id'=>$social_user->getId(), 'provider'=>$provider]

      );
      return $user;

    }else{


      $user_id = $authuser->user_id;

      $userdata = Constant_model::getDataOneColumn('users',"id",$user_id);

      $user = User::firstOrCreate(['email'=> $userdata[0]->email],
        ['ip_address'=> $userdata[0]->ip_address,
        'username'=> $userdata[0]->username,
        'name'=> $userdata[0]->name,
        'picture'=> $userdata[0]->picture,
        ],


    );


      return $user;

    }
}


public function logout(){

  Auth::logout();
  return redirect('/');
}


}
```

Comment: your code is pretty good. can't find any logical error. can you provide some debug data like $userdata that is provided from the Constant_model? I am pretty sure have some issue in here. you can debug from here.

Comment: But else part is working okay because else will call when user already register and if user already registered, successfully loggedin...

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Reference https://www.tutsmake.com/laravel-6-facebook-login-tutorial-example

```
public function redirect($provider)
 {
     return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
 }

 public function callback($provider)
 {
   $getInfo = Socialite::driver($provider)->user(); 
   $user = $this->createUser($getInfo,$provider); 
   auth()->login($user); 
   return redirect()->to('/home');
 }

 public function createUser($getInfo,$provider)
 {
   $user = User::where('provider_id', $getInfo->id)->first();
   if (!$user) {
      $user = User::create([
         'name'     => $getInfo->name,
         'email'    => $getInfo->email,
         'provider' => $provider,
         'provider_id' => $getInfo->id
     ]);
   }
   return $user;
 }
```